# ZF2: Form in view helper

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-form

I've created a view helper to be used as a sidebar widget for newsletter subscription. Following the official zf2 tutorial for creating forms, i've added used the addAction's code inside __invoke()..

```
namespace Application\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Application\Model\NewsletterTable;
use Application\Form\NewsletterForm;


class Newsletter extends AbstractHelper
{ 
    protected $newsletterTable;

    public function __construct(NewsletterTable $newsletterTable)
    {
        $this->newsletterTable = $newsletterTable;
    }

    public function __invoke()
    {      
        $form = new NewsletterForm();
        $form->get('submit')->setValue('Subscribe');

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isPost()) {
            $newsletter = new Newsletter();
            $form->setInputFilter($newsletter->getInputFilter());
            $form->setData($request->getPost());

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $newsletter->exchangeArray($form->getData());
                $this->getNewsletterTable()->saveEmail($newsletter);
            }
        }

        return array('form' => $form);            
    } 

    public function getNewsletterTable()
    {
        if (!$this->newsletterTable) {
            $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
            $this->newsletterTable = $sm->get('Application\Model\NewsletterTable');
        }
        return $this->newsletterTable;
    }      
}
```

The following code returns an error message:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Application\View\Helper\Newsletter::getRequest()...
```

Do i have to include some additional code that is not mentioned in the tutorial because i'm using the code in the helper file?

Answer (score 1):

You should not be handling the form request from your viewhelper!
That is a job for the controller.

Use the viewhelper to get the form, but post to a dedicated page(with it's own controller/action) and handle the form request on that page.